# Copy multiple files to Documents directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to copy multiple files from my NSBundle to Documents directory when the application launches.

This is the code to copy a file:

```
- (NSString *) getPath 
{
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  return [documentsDir stringByAppendingString:@"Photo.png"];
}

- (void) copyFile 
{
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  NSError *error;
  NSString *Path = [self getPath];
  BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:Path];

  if(!success) {

    NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Photo.png"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:Path error:&error];

    if (!success)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
}
```

The copyFile method will be called in the 'applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions' method. But this method only allows copying of one file to the Documents directory. If I want to copy 50 files from my NSBundle, does that mean I have to specify 50 paths? Is there any shorter way for example getting all the files in NSBundle with just few lines of codes?

Answer (score 6):

You can copy all files from your resource folders, but I doubt you really want to do that, do you? After all these are also app resources (like a strings file or graphics only for UI buttons, etc.)

So you may want to have a sub-directory in your resources folder (e.g. named `FilesToCopy`) with all the files you want to copy (e.g. `Photo.png` is found at `Contents/Resources/FilesToCopy/Photo.png`)

To get the content of a directory, just use

```
NSError * err;
NSArray * files;
NSString * srcPath;
NSString * dstPath;
NSFileManager * man;

srcPath = [self getSrcPath];
dstPath = [self getDstPath];
man = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
files = [man contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:srcPath error:&err];
```

Then you can copy one file at a time:

```
for (NSString *aFile in files) {
    BOOL success;

    NSString * srcFile = [srcPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFile];
    NSString * dstFile = [dstPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFile];
    success = [man copyItemAtPath:srcFile toPath:dstFile error:&err];
    // Verify success
}
```

Now you only need `srcPath` and `dstPath`.

```
- (NSString *)getSrcPath
{
     return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FilesToCopy"];
}

- (NSString *)getDstPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer to the question. Thanks Mecki.

Comment: One important thing to remember is to choose 'Create folder references' from the dialog box when dragging them into your project. If you just create a group the code will not find the folder, because it's a group, and so it will not enumerate the files, and no copying will take place.

Answer (score 0):

Change your functions' prototype:

```
- (NSString *) getPathofFileName:(NSString*)name;
- (void) copyFileWithName:(NSString*)name;
```

Comment: @Lloydworth Because then you can call `copyFileWithName` 50 times, each time giving another file name and `copyFileWithName` can call `getPathOfFileName` each time with a different file name to get the path for the current file copied. Of course this still means you need a list of all those 50 files. So this is not really a convenient solution.

Answer (score 0):

yeah sure you can do it

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    NSMutableArray *filesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0.epub",@"1.epub",@"2.epub",@"3.epub",@"4.epub",nil];//here put the name of files you want to copy
    [self copyFilesToDocuments:filesArray];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    self.window.rootViewController = (UIViewController*)self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void) copyFilesToDocuments : (NSMutableArray*)filesArr {
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,        NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < [filesArr count] ; i++) {
        NSString *filePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filesArr objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        BOOL exist = [fm fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
        NSError *error = nil;

        if (!exist) {
            NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filesArr objectAtIndex:i]];
            BOOL success = [fm copyItemAtPath:path toPath:filePath error:&error];
            if (!success) {
                NSAssert1(0,@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```